# Replace The object at index of NSMutablearray objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios

main array  :

```
    (
    "Thursday, Apr 18,2013",
    xyz,
        (
        "give ",
        "lv"
    ),
        (
        "wed",
        "mon"
    )

  )
```

For Main Array i need to add sub array:

```
Sub Array : (
  "hi"
)
```

When click on some x button sub array objects increces example :

```
Sub Array : (
"hi"
"hello"
)
```

how can i add to Main Array?

Comment: Tried something? Welcome to SO .

Comment: Your JSON data structure is ambigous. If you are using array make sure that indvidual items have same datatypes. From your question I assume you want to add a key with "SubArray: and its contents are editable?

Comment: I find it strange that you wrote "Replace The object at index" but didn't find `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` on NSMutableArray

Answer (score 5):

You can use :

```
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:newObject];
```